# One word to describe experiencing a "lack of idea" or lack of subject, lack of topic etc

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that would denote the lack of an idea.

For example, I am experiencing a lack of ideas to write an essay about. Or a lack of ideas to make a cartoon about.

Answer (score 5):

Specific to creative writing, the term is [Writer's Block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Writer's_block):

> Writer's block is a condition, primarily associated with writing, in which an author loses the ability to produce new work, or experiences a creative slowdown. <sub>(Wikipedia)</sub>

For other disciplines, the analogous term '**creative block**' is [gaining currency](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/creating-in-flow/201209/10-creative-block-breakers-actually-work).

---

A more general word applicable to other disciplines would be **[stuck](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stick)**:

> 4.2 ***be/get stuck*** Be unable to progress with a task or find the answer or solution to something <sub>(Oxford)</sub>

---

If you experience diffculty thinking of a new topic, you could also say that you're

**[drawing a blank](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/draw_a_blank)**

> Elicit no successful response; fail <sub>(Oxford)</sub>

Comment: Thanks, but here rather than getting stuck during, it is more about not being able to begin with it.

Comment: @jinphysio: See edit. Moreover, creative/writer's block is applicable to both. As in, writer's block could prevent you from starting your new novel, or from finishing your third act.

Answer (score 0):

You have **"a blank mind".** or **"a mental block"**.

> - [**someone's mind goes blank**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/blank) - used for saying that someone becomes unable to remember or think anything"
> - [**mental block**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/someone-s-mind-is-goes-blank) - "an inability to remember or think of something you normally can do"

"I was so nervous during the interview that when I was asked about my experience, **my mind went blank**."

"When he asked me for my number, **my mind went completely blank**."

"A **mental block** is the inability to cognitively process thoughts or recall information."

"A state of **mental block** is when the mind tells us that we are incapable or inept at a particular task, whereas our sensibilities tell us that we are capable enough to complete that work."

Answer (score 0):

Although I’ve not been able to find any example to illustrate its use or a reference body listing the phrase as an acceptable way to describe the situation you have mentioned, however, upon reading your problem statement, it is the first phrase, not exactly a word, that made an appearance in the conscious part of the brain from somewhere:

**Literary Blackout**

Merriam Webster defines **Blackout** as**:**

> a period of darkness, either enforced or caused by some sort of
>   failure.

As ideas constitute flashes of lightening or imagination, hence your situation perfectly fits the definition that some sort of a failure — in my case, it usually happens when an exceptionally incompetent person repeatedly prevails in holding my faculties hostage — prevents the light or a bolt of imagination to reach you resulting in little to no intellectual activity in the conscious or even subconscious part of your brain; consequently, you feel starved for ideas. It can also happen because of dearth of knowledge.